# Programing Logistic regression with Stochastic gradient descent in R

Tags: r, regression, gradient-descent, stochastic

I’m trying to program the logistic regression with stochastic descending gradient in R. For example I have followed the example of Andrew Ng named: “ex2data1.txt”.

The point is that the algorithm works properly, but thetas estimation is not exactly what I expected. So I tried to change whole algorithm in order to solve this issue.  However, it was almost impossible to me. I was not able to detect the error which is causing this problem.  Thus, It would be very useful if someone could check the example and tell me why thetas are not being calculated correctly. I really appreciate it.

Regarding the programming, *I'm not using any function implemented* in R *or matrix calculation*. I’m just using sums and subtractions in loops  due to I want to use the code in hadoop and  I cannot use matrix calculus or even functions which are already programed in R such as "sum", "sqrt", etc

**Stochastic Gradient Descent is:**

```
Loop {
   for i = 1 to m, {
     θj := θj + α(y(i) - hθ(x(i)))(xj)(i)
  }
}`
```

And Logistic regression: [image: link to image]

My code is:

```
data1 <- read.table("~/ex2data1.txt", sep = ",")
names(data1) <- c("Exam1", "Exam2", "Admit")

# Sample the data for stochastic gradient decent 

ss<-data1[sample(nrow(data1),size=nrow(data1),replace=FALSE),]

x <- with(ss, matrix(cbind(1, Exam1), nrow = nrow(ss)))
y <- c(ss$Admit)
m <- nrow(x)

# startup parameters

iterations<-1
j<-vector()
alpha<-0.05
theta<-c(0,0)



#My loop

while(iterations<=10){

    coste<-c(0,0)
    suma<-0

    for(i in 1:m){

        # h<-1/(1+exp(-Q*x)

        h<-1/(1+exp((-theta)*x[i,]))

        #Cost(hQ(x),y)=y(i)*log(hQ(x))+(1-y(i))*log(1-hQ(x))

            cost<-((y[i]*log(h))+((1-y[i])*log(1-h)))

        #sum(cost) i=1 to m

            suma<-suma+cost

        #Diferences=(hQ(x(i))-y(i))*x(i)

            difference<-(h-y[i])*x[i,]  

        #sum the differences 

            coste<-coste+difference

        #calculation thetas and upgrade = Qj:= Qj - alpha* sum((h-y[i])*x[i,]*x(i))

            theta[1]<-(theta[1]-alpha*1/m*(coste[1]))
            theta[2]<-(theta[2]-alpha*1/m*(coste[2]))

    }
        #J(Q)=(-1/m)* sum ( y(i)*log(hQ(x))+(1-y(i))*log(1-hQ(x)))

            j[iterations]<-(-1/m)*suma

            iterations=iterations+1

}



#If I compare my thetas with R glm 


Call:  glm(formula = y ~ x[, 2], family = binomial("logit"), data = data1)

Coefficients:

Intercept:-4.71816 

x[, 2]  :0.08091
```

**My thetas**

```
Intercept: 0.4624024 
 x[,2]: 1.3650234
```

Answer (score 6):

I have implemented a solution in R for the other Ng's example set: ex2data2.txt. Here is my code:

```
sigmoid <- function(z) {
return(1/(1 + exp(-z)))
}


mapFeature <- function(X1, X2) {
degree <- 6
out <- rep(1, length(X1))
for (i in 1:degree) {
for (j in 0:i) {
out <- cbind(out, (X1^(i - j)) * (X2^j))
}
}
return(out)
}


## Cost Function
fr <- function(theta, X, y, lambda) {
m <- length(y)
return(1/m * sum(-y * log(sigmoid(X %*% theta)) - (1 - y) *
log(1 - sigmoid(X %*% theta))) + lambda/2/m * sum(theta[-1]^2))
}


## Gradient
grr <- function(theta, X, y, lambda) {
return(1/m * t(X) %*% (sigmoid(X %*% theta) - y) + lambda/m *
c(0, theta[-1]))
}

data <- read.csv("ex2data2.txt", header = F)
X = as.matrix(data[,c(1,2)])
y = data[,3]
X = mapFeature(X[,1],X[,2])
m <- nrow(X)
n <- ncol(X)
initial_theta = rep(0, n)
lambda <- 1
res <- optim(initial_theta, fr, grr, X, y, lambda,
method = "BFGS", control = list(maxit = 100000))
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for your answer,but Im just using sums and subtractions in loops due to I want to use the code in hadoop and I cannot use matrix calculus or even functions which are already programed in R such as "sum", "sqrt","optim", etc.

Comment: What is the purpose of the mapFeature function?

Comment: One way to fit the data better is to create more features from each data
point. In the provided function mapFeature.m, we will map the features into
all polynomial terms of x1 and x2 up to the sixth power. As a result of this mapping, our vector of two features (the scores on
two QA tests) has been transformed into a 28-dimensional vector. A logistic
regression classifier trained on this higher-dimension feature vector will have
a more complex decision boundary and will appear nonlinear when drawn in
our 2-dimensional plot.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't * be %*% in a few instances? E.g. 
`h<-1/(1+exp((-theta) %*% x[i,]))` instead of  `h<-1/(1+exp((-theta)*x[i,]))`